# Proving isomorphism between Martin-Lof's equality and Path Induction in Coq

Tags: equality, coq, ssreflect

I am studying Coq and trying to prove the isomorphism between Martin-Lof's equality and the Path Induction's one.

I defined the two equalities as follows.

```
Module MartinLof.

Axiom eq : forall A, A -> A -> Prop.
Axiom refl : forall A, forall x : A, eq A x x.
Axiom el : forall (A : Type) (C : forall x y : A, eq A x y -> Prop),
  (forall x : A, C x x (refl A x)) ->
    forall a b : A, forall p : eq A a b, C a b p.

End MartinLof.

Module PathInduction.
Axiom eq : forall A, A -> A -> Prop.
Axiom refl : forall A, forall x : A, eq A x x.
Axiom el : forall (A : Type) (x : A) (P : forall a : A, eq A x a -> Prop), 
    P x (refl A x) -> forall y : A, forall p : eq A x y, P y p.

End PathInduction.
```

And I defined the two functions involved in the isomorphism as follows.

```
Definition f {A} : forall x y: A, forall m: MartinLof.eq A x y, PathInduction.eq A x y.
Proof.
apply: (MartinLof.el A (fun a b p => PathInduction.eq A a b) _ x y m).
move=> x0.
exact: PathInduction.refl A x0.
Defined.

Definition g {A} : forall x y: A, forall p: PathInduction.eq A x y, MartinLof.eq A x y.
Proof.
apply: (PathInduction.el A x (fun a p => MartinLof.eq A x a) _ y p).
exact: MartinLof.refl A x.
Defined.
```

Now I am trying to define the following proof-terms, but I cannot move from the initial statement because I actually don't know what tactic to apply.

```
Definition pf1 {A}:  forall x y: A, forall m: MartinLof.eq A x y,
  eq m (g x y (f x y m)).

Definition pf2 {A} : forall x y: A, forall p: PathInduction.eq A x y, 
  eq p (f x y (g x y p)).
```

I through I could simplify the expression

```
(g x y (f x y m))
```

but I don't know how to do that. Does anyone know how I can go on on this proof?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that your definition of the identity types is incomplete, because it does not specify how `el` interacts with `refl`.  Here is a complete solution.

```
From mathcomp Require Import ssreflect.

Module MartinLof.

Axiom eq : forall A, A -> A -> Prop.
Axiom refl : forall A, forall x : A, eq A x x.
Axiom el : forall (A : Type) (C : forall x y : A, eq A x y -> Prop),
  (forall x : A, C x x (refl A x)) ->
    forall a b : A, forall p : eq A a b, C a b p.
Axiom el_refl : forall (A : Type) (C : forall x y : A, eq A x y -> Prop)
    (CR : forall x : A, C x x (refl A x)),
    forall x : A, el A C CR x x (refl A x) = CR x.

End MartinLof.

Module PathInduction.
Axiom eq : forall A, A -> A -> Prop.
Axiom refl : forall A, forall x : A, eq A x x.
Axiom el : forall (A : Type) (x : A) (P : forall a : A, eq A x a -> Prop),
    P x (refl A x) -> forall y : A, forall p : eq A x y, P y p.
Axiom el_refl : forall (A : Type) (x : A) (P : forall y : A, eq A x y -> Prop)
    (PR : P x (refl A x)),
    el A x P PR x (refl A x) = PR.

End PathInduction.

Definition f {A} (x y: A) (m: MartinLof.eq A x y) : PathInduction.eq A x y.
Proof.
apply: (MartinLof.el A (fun a b p => PathInduction.eq A a b) _ x y m).
move=> x0.
exact: PathInduction.refl A x0.
Defined.

Definition g {A} (x y: A) (p: PathInduction.eq A x y) : MartinLof.eq A x y.
Proof.
apply: (PathInduction.el A x (fun a p => MartinLof.eq A x a) _ y p).
exact: MartinLof.refl A x.
Defined.

Definition pf1 {A} (x y: A) (m: MartinLof.eq A x y) : eq m (g x y (f x y m)).
Proof.
apply: (MartinLof.el A (fun x y p => p = g x y (f x y p))) => x0.
by rewrite /f MartinLof.el_refl /g PathInduction.el_refl.
Qed.

Definition pf2 {A} (x y: A) (m: PathInduction.eq A x y) : eq m (f x y (g x y m)).
Proof.
apply: (PathInduction.el A x (fun y p => p = f x y (g x y p))).
by rewrite /f /g PathInduction.el_refl MartinLof.el_refl.
Qed.
```

Alternatively, you could have just *defined* the two identity types as Coq inductive types, which would have given you the same principles without the need to state separate axioms; Coq's computation behavior already yields the equations you need.  I have used pattern-matching syntax, but similar definitions are possible using the standard combinators `eq1_rect` and `eq2_rect`.

```
Inductive eq1 (A : Type) (x : A) : A -> Type :=
| eq1_refl : eq1 A x x.

Inductive eq2 (A : Type) : A -> A -> Type :=
| eq2_refl x : eq2 A x x.

Definition f {A} {x y : A} (p : eq1 A x y) : eq2 A x y :=
  match p with eq1_refl _ _ => eq2_refl A x end.

Definition g {A} {x y : A} (p : eq2 A x y) : eq1 A x y :=
  match p with eq2_refl _ z => eq1_refl A z end.

Definition fg {A} (x y : A) (p : eq2 A x y) : f (g p) = p :=
  match p with eq2_refl _ _ => eq_refl end.

Definition gf {A} (x y : A) (p : eq1 A x y) : g (f p) = p :=
  match p with eq1_refl _ _ => eq_refl end.
```

Although not immediately clear, `eq1` corresponds to your `PathInduction.eq`, and `eq2` corresponds to your `MartinLof.eq`. You can check this by asking Coq to print the types of their recursion principles:

```
Check eq1_rect.
Check eq2_rect.
```

You may notice that I have defined the two in `Type` instead of `Prop`.  I just did this to make the recursion principles generated by Coq closer to the ones you had; by default, Coq uses simpler recursion principles for things defined in `Prop` (though that behavior can be changed with a few commands).

Comment: Sorry @Artur, just one more question. If I had to do the same, but using the Leibniz's equality instead of Path Induction, how could I define Leibniz's equality using inductive types? I am trying to do so, but I am in trouble since I don't know how to specify the difference in the dependent type.

Comment: It depends on what you mean by "Leibniz equality." Note that Coq's standard equality (`=`, which is infix syntax for `eq`) is actually an inductive proposition: its definition really just `eq1` given above.

Comment: Yes I know, and if I am not wrong it is equivalent to the Leibniz one. The difference I meant was about the dependent type. In `eq1` the elimination type depends on a inhabitant `P x (refl A x)`. On the other hand with Leibniz the elimination type does not depend on the proof-term `refl A x`, but only on `P x x`. I mean, instead of having a proof of equality as second "parameter" there's just `x`.

Comment: But what exactly do you mean by "Leibniz equality"? The standard equality in Coq? Or something else?

Comment: Something else. I actually find it difficult to explain. During lectures, my professor explained four types of equality: à la Gentzen (https://ibb.co/imQOCF), Leibniz (https://ibb.co/n0uBzv), Martin-Lof (https://ibb.co/fALZKv) and with Path Induction (https://ibb.co/esZuKv). The links point to the rules she gave us. 

The difference among these four types rely on the type C. I find it difficult to formalize the first and the second with inductive types because I cannot find a way to specify that type.

Comment: I see. I have an answer, but I think it is easier for you to post this as a different question.

Comment: Yes, you're right. Here is the link to the new question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45495135/defining-different-equality-types-as-inductive-types-in-coq . I cannot thank you enough for your help!